# Aws::SQS::Errors::NonExistentQueue (The specified queue default does not exist.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have created a worker machine at AWS and SQS named as queue123 and I am using shoryuken gem as adapter (    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :shoryuken  at application.rb ).

```
class EmailVerificationMailerJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as 'queue123'

  def perform(user)
    EmailVerificationMailer.send_email_otp(user)
  end
end
```

when the request hits job it shows

> Aws::SQS::Errors::NonExistentQueue (The specified queue default does not exist.): error.

What I am missing here.

Comment: Did queue is mention here is exist in SQS?

Comment: Yes. That is a queue exixts in SQS

Comment: @Aarthi are you sending the request to the correct AWS region?  Each region's SQS deployment is independent of the others.  If (for example) you create a queue in us-east-2 and this code runs against us-east-1, us-east-1 will correctly report that the queue does not exist.

Comment: Are you using the queue *name* in the request, or queue *url*? The distinction is important.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed to give permission expected permissions to the queue from `AWS Console`.

Try following steps -

1. Login to your `AWS Console`.
2. `right-click` on your queue.
3. Goto `Add a Permission`.
4. Select necessary account in `Principal` section.
5. Select required permissions you want to give to above users.
6. `Add permission` to save.